# Trim Cells in entire sheet, Overflow Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have my code which loads 2 workbooks, and copies them into a master workbook. However I am getting an

> overflow error

when i'm trying to trim all cells in the pasted sheets (too remove the spaces).

Does anyone know why this overflow error would occur when trimming excess blank spaces in a whole sheet? Specifically I am getting the error on this part `Target = Target.Value` .

```
Sub Load()
    LoadDailyWorkbook
    LoadLastWeeksWorkbook
End Sub

Sub LoadDailyWorkbook()
    Const A1BJ200 As String = "A1:BJ200"
    Const A1L3 As String = "A1:L3"
    Dim masterWB As Workbook
    Dim dailyWB As Workbook
    'Set Current Workbook as Master
    Set masterWB = Application.ThisWorkbook
    'Set some Workbook as the one you are copying from
    Set dailyWB = getWorkbook(Sheets("Control Manager").Range("O2"))

    If Not dailyWB Is Nothing Then
        With dailyWB
            'Copy the Range from dailyWB and Paste it into the MasterWB
            .Worksheets("Summary1").Range(A1BJ200).Copy masterWB.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1")
            TrimRange masterWB.Worksheets("Summary").Range(A1BJ200)
            'repeat for next Sheet
            .Worksheets("risk1").Range(A1BJ200).Copy masterWB.Worksheets("risk").Range("A1")
            TrimRange masterWB.Worksheets("risk").Range(A1BJ200)

            'repeat for CS sheet
            .Worksheets("CS today").Range(A1L3).Copy masterWB.Worksheets("CS").Range("A1").Rows("1:1")
            TrimRange masterWB.Worksheets("CS").Range(A1L3)
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With

    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadLastWeeksWorkbook()
    Const A1BJ200 As String = "A1:BJ200"
    Dim masterWB As Workbook
    Dim lastweekWB As Workbook

    'Set Current Workbook as Master
    Set masterWB = Application.ThisWorkbook

    ''''''''''''Get Last Week Data''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set lastweekWB = getWorkbook(Workbooks.Open(Sheets("Control Manager").Range("O3")))
    If Not lastweekWB Is Nothing Then
        With lastweekWB
            'repeat for next risk Sheet
            .Worksheets("risk2").Range(A1BJ200).Copy masterWB.Worksheets("risk_lastweek").Range("A1")
            TrimRange masterWB.Worksheets("risk_lastweek").Range(A1BJ200)

            TrimRange masterWB.Columns("A:BB")
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Function getWorkbook(FullName As String) As Workbook
    If Len(Dir(FullName)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox FullName & " not found found", vbCritical, "File Not Found"
    Else
        Set getWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FullName)
    End If
End Function

Sub TrimRange(Target As Range)
    Dim results As Variant
    Set Target = Intersect(Target.Parent.UsedRange, Target)
    If Target Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Target.Count = 1 Then
        Target.Value = Trim(Target.Value)
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Target = Target.Value

        Dim r As Long, c As Long
        For r = 1 To UBound(results)
            For c = 1 To UBound(results, 2)
                results(r, c) = Trim(results(r, c))
            Next
        Next
        Target.Value = results
    End If
    Target.Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really need to loop through every single cell in a column? This line especially scares me, `TrimRange masterWB.Columns("A:BB")`  Also, what's the point with `Target = Target.Value`, to paste the value of a formula?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub TrimRange(Target As Range)
    Dim results As Variant
```

And yet, you do not set `results` before you use it.

```
    For r = 1 To UBound(results)
```

So you are calling `UBound` on some thing that does not exist.

In addition, when I have changed formulas to values, I have used `Target.Value = Target.Value` instead of `Target = Target.Value`. I know the `.Value` is usually the default value, but I never trust implicit stuff to work all the time.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that this is my code.  I guess I screwed it up during an edit.  Unreal that I didn't catch the mistake.  Thanks

Comment: I have switched `Target = Target.value` to `results = Target.Value` . Still getting over flow error.  Are you saying instead of both of these to use `Target.Value = Target.Value`?

Comment: @excelguy - that is what I am saying for the case where you have `Target = Target.Value`. The other question here is how many cells are you selecting? A `Variant` is not an infinite size and will overflow if you try to stuff too large a range into it.

Comment: I want to copy the whole page, thats why I used `Columns`, Maybe I could shorten this, maybe it will make a difference. In reality I probably need A to Z. I'll give it a try.